# Rails How to pass params from controller to after_save inside model

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rfq contoller i am creating new or updating existing Rfqs, when i create or update the object is saved, what i want is as i have number of quotes params i want to update the line_items table with the quotes in params[:quotes] in quote_price column after saving the Rfqs

i know its confusing, but who are ror-ish should have got some hint wat i want to ask.

Comment: You could directly access `params[:quotes]` from the after_save block?

Comment: How can you explain with an example?

Comment: `params` is not directly accessible from the model, I don't think.

Comment: I have used an instance method to pass the params, but there is a way to pass after_save block.

Answer (score 14):

If you're trying to use the `params` hash in your model, you are violating principles of MVC. The model should stand alone with arguments. If you are trying to do the following:

```
# controller
Model.foo

# model
def foo
  params[:bar].reverse!
end
```

You should do the following instead:

```
# controller
Model.foo(params[:bar])

# model
def foo(foobar)
  foobar.reverse!
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly if it deals with `params`, it's probably a good idea to put that type of logic in the controller, lest you muddle the responsibilities of the model and controller.

That is, in the **controller**:

```
if @foo.save
  # Update line_items using params[:quotes]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to be able to have 1 form that saves both the main object and all of the child objects. If not, disregard.

In rails, this is named "nested_attributes"

you'll add this to your model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :quotes
# assuming you have 
has_many :quotes
```

and then in your form view:

```
<% form.fields_for :quotes do |child_form| %>
  <%= child_form.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

Check this out at Ryan's Blog: [Nested Attributes](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes)