# How to save attributes to a has_many :through join table with no existing records to build from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I have a form which creates a new Child record and a new Parent record using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Children and Parents have a `has_many :through` association like so:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :relationships
   has_many :parents, through: :relationships
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :parents
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :relationships, allow_destroy: true
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :relationships
   has_many :children, through: :relationships
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :child
   belongs_to :parent
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :parents

   #has :schedule attribute
end
```

I would like to set the `schedule` attribute in Relationships at the same time and can't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as I am manipulating some data in the controller to determine the `schedule` object before saving.

There are many answers on stack overflow for accomplishing this with a pre-existing parent record but I am having trouble finding any for a situation where none of the associations exist previously.

I have tried to do this with an `after_create` callback in the model but don't have access to `params` and have read that it is bad procedure to do so anyway. ( [Rails How to pass params from controller to after_save inside model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725185/rails-how-to-pass-params-from-controller-to-after-save-inside-model)).

Ideally I would like to set `schedule` in the same database call that creates the relationship record along with `child_id` and `parent_id`.

Any help with this would be awesome, thanks

**UPDATE**

Controller as of original post

```
def new
  @child = Child.new
end

def create
  @child = Child.new(params[:child])
  schedule = build_schedule(params)
  # Need to save schedule to @child.relationship[0].schedule somehow
  if @child.save!
    redirect_to admins_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def build_schedule(params)
  # works with params[:mon, :tue, :wed, :thu, :fri] to return a schedule object.
end
```

The `parent` is built using [Ryan Bates' nested form helper](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments). This is the build line from it:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    ...
  end
end
```

I am not building the `relationship` at all, it is magically built by rails as far as i'm aware.

Trying **Danny Van Hoof's** suggestion `@child.relationships[0].schedule =` i get `undefined method schedule=' for nil:NilClass` as no relationship exists.

If i build the relationship beforehand either in `new` or `create` action using `@child.relationship.build` I get 2 relationship records being saved:

[image: relationships table]

The one that I built has `schedule` saved but has no `parent_id` (parental_group_id)
The second record is the one build magically and has both correct ids but no `schedule`.

Now when trying **Rick Peck's** suggestion by adding

```
def params
    params.require(:child).permit(relationships_attributes: [:schedule])
    # tried with and without `parents_attributes`
end
```

I get a `stack level too deep` error on the `params.require` line. I also don't fully understand what this does. (I'm fairly new to rails)

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar construct as yours in one of my websites, it works fine, except that I (translated to your example) have

```
attr_accessible :relationships_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :relationships, allow_destroy: true
```

In my Relationship model, I then make parent_id accessible

This allows to, in the controller, to do something like

```
@child.relationships[0].schedule = ...
```

Even before saving the child

Or, alternatively, to set the schedule from your view immediately when entering the parent details

Just drop me a comment if not clear!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Danny. I've updated the question above to show what happened when I tried your code. In your app how are you creating your version of `Relationship`? And how did you assign both models `_id`'s to it? Cheers

Comment: I'm using nested_form to build my relationships. In your case, I would simply build it after you've saved the child. Something like child.build_relationship(parent: parent, schedule: schedule)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `accepts_nested_attributes_for` will have to include the `join model`, and then pass the data through to the other model, like this:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :relationships
   has_many :parents, through: :relationships

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :relationships
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :relationships
   has_many :children, through: :relationships
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :child
   belongs_to :parent

   #attr_accessor :schedule ?
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :parents
end

#app/controllers/child_controller.rb
def new
    @child = Child.new
    @child.relationships.build.parents.build
end

private
def params
    params.require(:child).permit(relationships_attributes: [:schedule, parents_attributes: [:variable-1, :variable-2]])
end
```

This will pass the required data to `relationships` and then onto `parents`. The `schedule` can be then handled when you handle the variables in the `relationships` model