# user_id not registering in an associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 4, here's my code:

```
# event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :participants
  has_many :users, through: :participants  
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :participants
  has_many :events, through: :participants
end

# events_controller.rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = current_user.events.new(event_params)
    if @event.save
      flash[:notice] = "Created event successfully."
      redirect_to event_path(@event)
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

When I create an event, the `user_id` in `@event` is `nil`. I am not sure why the `user_id` is not registered. I could fix this with:

```
# events_controller.rb
def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)
  @event.user_id = current_user.id
  ...
end
```

But wondering why the first approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@event = current_user.events.build(event_params)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflict in your relation's names:

```
# event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :participants
  has_many :user_participants, through: :participants  
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :participants
  has_many :events_participants, through: :participants
end
```

Also, this might be usefull for you: [How to save attributes to a has_many :through join table with no existing records to build from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295658/how-to-save-attributes-to-a-has-many-through-join-table-with-no-existing-record)